# How to load balance channel in Spring Webflux / RSocket

Tags: spring-webflux, rsocket

Assume we have service A and service B. Service A need to send infinite amount of data to service B. In spring webflux or rsocket, we could do it by making service A send flux and receive flux as well.

The problem lies when we have 1 service A and 10 service B. Service A will pick one of service B and stream the data to that specific service indefinitely, which can make only 1 service busy while others are idle.

Is there a way to stream the data from service A and divide the data stream to 10 service B? Can rsocket broker like netifi do that?

Comment: Hi. I don't thinks so it is possible. Because Webflux and RSocket is a stateful communication. Each connection is keeped.

Comment: Isn't there an Rsocket routing project that is attempting to solve this issue?